# Get all characters to right of last dash

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
string test = "9586-202-10072"
```

How would I get all characters to the right of the final `-` so 10072. The number of characters is always different to the right of the last dash.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

You can get the position of the last `-` with `str.LastIndexOf('-')`. So the next step is obvious:

```
var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

**Correction**:

As Brian states below, using this on a string with no dashes will result in the original string being returned.

**Additional**:

Since the introduction of C# 8 you can rewrite the code to use range indicator:

```
var result = str[(str.LastIndexOf('-') + 1)..];
```

Comment: This works even when the hyphen is the last character, in that case it correctly returns an empty string. This will only fail if either `str` is null or if it doesn't contain a hyphen at all. (In the case where there's no hyphen it doesn't throw; it returns the entire source string.)

Comment: @LukeH: Thanks for the heads up. I didn't check and mistakenly assumed it would throw.

Comment: Well, `LastIndexOf` returns -1 if nothing is found (this is documented behavior, so it is safe to rely on it).  `str.Substring(1-1)` gives you a string equal to `str`.  No surprises, here.

Comment: @Brian: I think I broke my record for most mistakes in the same trivial statement. Lesson: don't ever write anything without proofreading the code after the fact. Thanks.

Answer (score 77):

You could use LINQ, and save yourself the explicit parsing:

```
string test = "9586-202-10072";
string lastFragment = test.Split('-').Last();

Console.WriteLine(lastFragment);
```

Comment: This will probably save the most developer time, but in the general case note that code like this will many string allocations (probably four in the example above) so might be deemphasized in performance-critical sections.

Answer (score 6):

I can see this post was viewed over 46,000 times.  I would bet many of the 46,000 viewers are asking this question simply because they just want the file name... and these answers can be a rabbit hole if you cannot make your substring verbatim using the at sign.

If you simply want to get the file name, then there is a simple answer which should be mentioned here. Even if it's not the precise answer to the question.

```
result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
YourString.Substring(YourString.LastIndexOf("-"));
```

Comment: if you exclude "+ 1" at the end, then the output will contain special character along with the string.

Answer (score 4):

```
string tail = test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

With the latest `C#` 8 and later you can use [Range Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes) as follows:-

```cs
string test = "9586-202-10072"

var foo = test?[(test.LastIndexOf('-') + 1)..];

// foo is => 10072
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string atest = "9586-202-10072";
int indexOfHyphen = atest.LastIndexOf("-");

if (indexOfHyphen >= 0)
{
    string contentAfterLastHyphen = atest.Substring(indexOfHyphen + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(contentAfterLastHyphen );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [String.lastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28VS.71%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 1):

I created a string extension for this, hope it helps.

```
public static string GetStringAfterChar(this string value, char substring)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            var index = value.LastIndexOf(substring);
            return index > 0 ? value.Substring(index + 1) : value;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test.Substring[(test.LastIndexOf('-') + 1)..]
```

C# 8 (late 2019) introduces `range` operator and simplifies it a bit further. The two dots here means from the index (inclusive) till the end of string.

Comment: I was about to post the same for some easy reputation, after VS suggested me this refactor. But you were first; here you go, upvoted. :P

Answer (score 0):

`test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf("-"))`

Answer (score 0):

and... in case you need the left part of a string:

```
private string AllTheLeftPart(string theString)
{       
    string rightPart = theString.Substring(theString.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);

    string leftPart theString.Replace("-" + rightPart, String.Empty);

    return leftPart ;
}
```