# Add space between colon in a string

Tags: c#, .net

**Expected User Inputs:**

```
Apple : 100

Apple:100

Apple: 100

Apple :100

Apple   :   100

Apple  :100

Apple:  100
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Apple : 100
```

I need only 1 space between the colon `:`

**Code:**

```
 string input = "Apple:100";

 if (input.Contains(":"))
 {
    string firstPart = input.Split(':').First();

    string lastPart = input.Split(':').Last();

    input = firstPart.Trim() + " : " + lastPart.Trim();
 }
```

Above code is working using `Linq`, but is there shorter or efficient code with performance in mind ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Performance in mind? Is this slow? How often is this executed?

Comment: @trailmax , it is executed many times.

Comment: @trailmax this can be veeeeery slow, for string manipulation a StringBuilder is always faster that this

Comment: Is it possible that the user input contains spaces, that are not trailing or leading the :? For example, "Big Apple : 100"

Comment: If I understand what you want right and if  it's surely will be " 1 word followed by comma followed by number" format always, remove all spaces and then replace ":" with "  :   " ? Not sure about performance of this approach though.

Comment: @JoshuaVdM , user can add spaces accidentally :)

Comment: Splitting the input *once* and storing it in a variable would make your code faster.  There's no point splitting it twice.

Comment: @EgeBayrak , I tried to `Replace` method but it adds a extra space.

Comment: @stom Well what I meant to ask is, if a user adds a whitespace like that accidentally, should it also be removed? Or should only whitespace around the colon be removed?

Comment: @JoshuaVdM , I need only 1 space around the colon :

Comment: @stom weird, it shouldn't do so unless coded that way.

Comment: _a StringBuilder is always faster_ No it isn't. There are no repeated string assignments needed. Setting up a StringBuilder is not free either.

Comment: is it guaranteed that the word (Apple) will not contain any whitespace ?

Comment: @SelmanGenç , Spaces can be after or before Apple but not in the word apple itself.

Comment: @stom I have provided two solutions, the second one may not work if space comes before apple, I leave fixing that to you :)

Comment: I raced a lot of the suggestions here and found my own to be the fastest ;-) It took 0.17 seconds for 100000 iterations of the above training set. The slowest was about 0.8 seconds, so I seriously doubt that this code will be your bottle neck. Just get rid of the double split (that ran in 0.289 seconds instead of 0.375) and you're good to go.

Comment: @PalleDue , Appreciate Thank you. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this one liner:

```
input = string.Join(" : ", input.Split(':').Select(x => x.Trim()));
```

This is more efficient than splitting two times. However, if you want a more efficient solution you can use `StringBuilder`:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
char? previousChar = null;
foreach (var ch in input)
{
    // don't add multiple whitespace
    if (ch == ' ' && previousChar == ch)
    {
        continue;
    }

     // add space before colon
     if (ch == ':' && previousChar != ' ')
     {
         builder.Append(' ');
     }

     // add space after colon
     if (previousChar == ':' && ch != ' ')
     {
          builder.Append(' ');
     }


    builder.Append(ch);
    previousChar = ch;
}
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comments by @Jimi seems like the foreach version is slower than LINQ.

Comment: I find the name `lastChar` a little disturbing, since last can also mean ultimate. Wouldn't `prevChar` be more appropriate?

Comment: @PalleDue yes, it makes more sense. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: One liner is good one :), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5327629/2218697) post said `Linq` has performance issue, what you suggest ?

Comment: Appreciate Thank you. :)

Comment: Tested it over 1 Million iterations (multiple times). As it is, the Linq method is more efficient than the `StringBuilder` one (16~20%). This is because the SB method is not very efficient in itself. Appending the results of `IndexOf(':')` and `SubString()`  (those are quite optimized) would increase the speed about 3x times. Beating Linq of -50% relative time.

Comment: @Jimi hmm, interesting. so I bothered to write all that code for nothing, lol :) thanks for the benchmarks, I will still keep the foreach version for an alternative, but I will update the answer with the benchmark info

Comment: @stom LINQ is not inherently less performant.  I'm not sure where you got your info, but it isn't accurate.  LINQ does tend to be *misused*, which can lead to less performant code, I suppose.

Comment: Well, in that test (1M iterations * 10 times) the Linq method (for each iteration) completed in 246~258ms. The `StringBuilder` method in 302~323ms. But a `StringBuilder` method using `IndexOf()` + `SubString()`, 92~102Ms. This one: `string output = string.Join(" : ", input.Split(new[] { ":", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));` 188~201ms. I think is also to remember that the Linq `.Select()` method can't be cached. If you were to use `.Except()` or `.Where()` instead (those are cached), in an iteration, Linq couldn't be beaten by anything else (for (;;) included).

Comment: I would expect string builder to be faster because there are less string allocations. How are you benchmarking them? are you using Benchmark.NET ?

Comment: Nope. Just a `StopWatch` for all of them (but in an environment I use for testing). I understand that a test like this, repeated 10 times, is not a real benchmark (if `The General` comes by, he has a *proprietary* benchmark test that could be much more revealing) but it provides a clue, nonetheless. However, `StringBuilder` used to just concatenate strings (as reported before), beats the same Linq method.

Comment: @Jimi , Thank you, Your solution is working :) , are you sure `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` is faster than using `Linq Select` with `Trim()`  ?

Comment: @stom   I saw your previous comment (I was working). If you think it could useful, I can post a couple of examples that perform better (note, a few milliseconds over 1 million operations) than a Linq `.Select()` method. As I have already mentioned, a `StringBuilder.Append()` performs even better than `string.Join().Split()`. You can test them yourself. I can post (as soon as I have some time) an example that uses a `StopWatch()` to measure the timings, since you already have a bunch of answers here.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this old-fashioned string manipulation:

```
int colonPos = input.IndexOf(':');
if (colonPos>-1)
{
    string s1 = input.Substring(0,colonPos).Trim();
    string s2 = input.Substring(colonPos+1, input.Length-colonPos-1).Trim();
    string result = $"{s1} : {s2}";
}
```

Whether it is more performant, I don't know, [Race Your Horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

**Edit**:
This one is even faster and simpler (completed 100000 iterations of the training set in 0.132 seconds):

```
string result = input.Replace(" ","").Replace(":", " : ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked, here's a comparison between similar methods:

The two methods that [Selman Genç](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078952/add-space-between-colon-in-a-string?answertab=active#tab-top) presented and two other that differ in some details.

**`string.Join("[Separator]", string.Split())`**

This method glues together, using a Separator, the array of strings generated by `.Split(char[])`, which creates a string for each substring of the original one. The substrings are generated using the characters specified in the char array parameter as separator identifiers.
The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter indicates to only return non-empty substrings.

```
string output = string.Join(" : ", input.Split(new[] { ":", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

**`StringBuilder.Append(SubString(IndexOf([Separator])))`**
(non optimized: `TrimStart()` and `TrimEnd()` are used here)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
const string Separator = " : ";
int SplitPosition = input.IndexOf(':');
sb.Append(input.Substring(0, SplitPosition).TrimEnd());
sb.Append(Separator);
sb.Append(input.Substring(SplitPosition + 1).TrimStart());
```

Here are the result of the test in 5 different conditions:
(Where I remind myself to always test the `.exe` and not the `IDE`)

> Debug Mode 32Bit - Visual Studio IDE
>  Debug Mode 64Bit - Visual
>   Studio IDE
>  Release Mode 64Bit - Visual Studio IDE
>  Debug Mode 64Bit - Executable File
>  Release Mode 64Bit - Executable File

```
Test Machine: I5 4690K on Asus Z-97K MB
Visual Studio 15.8.2
C# 7.3

==========================================
     1 Million iterations x 10 times           
          Code Optimization: On
==========================================
-------------------------------------------
                Debug 32Bit                
-------------------------------------------

Selman Genç Join(.Split().Select()): 244 ~ 247 ms
Selman Genç StringBuilder:           299 ~ 303 ms 
Counter Test Join(.Split()):         187 ~ 226 ms
Counter Test StringBuilder:           90 ~  95 ms

-------------------------------------------
                Debug 64Bit                
-------------------------------------------

Selman Genç Join(.Split().Select()): 242 ~ 259 ms
Selman Genç StringBuilder:           292 ~ 302 ms 
Counter Test Join(.Split()):         183 ~ 227 ms
Counter Test StringBuilder:           89 ~  93 ms

-------------------------------------------
               Release 64Bit                
-------------------------------------------

Selman Genç Join(.Split().Select()): 235 ~ 253 ms
Selman Genç StringBuilder:           288 ~ 302 ms 
Counter Test Join(.Split()):         176 ~ 224 ms
Counter Test StringBuilder:           86 ~  94 ms

-------------------------------------------
          Debug 64Bit - .exe File               
-------------------------------------------

Selman Genç Join(.Split().Select()): 232 ~ 234 ms
Selman Genç StringBuilder:            45 ~  47 ms 
Counter Test Join(.Split()):         197 ~ 217 ms
Counter Test StringBuilder:           77 ~  78 ms

-------------------------------------------
         Release 64Bit - .exe File               
-------------------------------------------

Selman Genç Join(.Split().Select()): 226 ~ 228 ms
Selman Genç StringBuilder:            45 ~  48 ms 
Counter Test Join(.Split()):         190 ~ 208 ms
Counter Test StringBuilder:           73 ~  77 ms
```

Sample test:

```
string input = "Apple   :   100";

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

// Counter test StringBuilder    
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
const string Separator = " : ";
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    int SplitPosition = input.IndexOf(':');
    sb1.Append(input.Substring(0, SplitPosition).TrimEnd());
    sb1.Append(Separator);
    sb1.Append(input.Substring(SplitPosition + 1).TrimStart());
    sb1.Clear();
}
sw.Stop();
//File write
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();

// Selman Genç StringBuilder    
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    char? previousChar = null;
    foreach (var ch in input)
    {
        if (ch == ' ' && previousChar == ch) { continue; }
        if (ch == ':' && previousChar != ' ') { sb2.Append(' '); }
        if (previousChar == ':' && ch != ' ') { sb2.Append(' '); }

        sb2.Append(ch);
        previousChar = ch;
    }
    sb2.Clear();
}

sw.Stop();
//File write
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    string output = string.Join(" : ", input.Split(':').Select(x => x.Trim()));
}

sw.Stop();

/*(...)
*/
```

Comment: Appreciate The Work , Thank you :)

Comment: @stom  Take a close look at the timings. What I previously said is not accurate. When run from the executable, the `StringBuilder` method @Selman Genç provided is the most performat. That's completly different in the VS Environment, where it's the opposite. Since that method doesn't use any "external" helper (like a version of `Trim()`), it's the most *predictable* at run-time. The sum of it is, when string concatenation is performed, `StringBuilder` is the best tool available.

Comment: At least somebody took a scientific approach and _measured_ the outcome. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You indicated that the first word would not have any spaces.  So in my opinion the most efficient, non-regex solution would be to remove all whitespace from the string (since you dont want any), then just replace the `:` with `:`

```
string input = "Apple   :     100";
input = new string(input.ToCharArray()
                 .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                 .ToArray());
input = input.Replace(":", " : ");
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4skhwj)

Comment: Spaces can be after or before Apple but not in the word apple itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex:

```
string input = "Apple:            100";

// Matches zero or more whitespace characters (\s*) followed by 
// a colon and zero or more whitespace characters
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*:\s*", " : "); // Result: "Apple : 100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how much performance a string builder and shortening to an array will do but you could try something like this.

```
string input = "Apple:100";

if (input.Contains(":"))
{
  string[] parts = input.Split(':');

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.Append(parts[0].Trim());
  builder.Append(" : ");
  builder.Append(parts[1].Trim());
  input = builder.ToString();
}
```